# Перенос значения из php в javaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Почему значения из `php` не переносятся в `js`. Что тут не так?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
idd = <?=$myrow['id2']?>;
id = <?=$myrow['id']?>;
document.write(id2);
document.write(id);
</script>
```

Comment: Попробуйте вот так:

 var idd = '<?=$myrow['id2']?>';
 var id = '<?=$myrow['id']?>';
 document.write(id2);
 document.write(id);

Comment: Данные присваиваются, но не выводятся

Comment: @Dedaster это у Вас ошибке, по этому и не выводится! Единственное что сделал @lampa это склпипастил ваш код и добавил `var` чем объявил переменную в текущей области видимости.

Comment: Я увидел и исправил коментарий.

Comment: А у него как и у меня присваивается, но не выводится даже при исправлении

Comment: @Palmervan а еще кавычки добавил. Судя по ответам, у автора в php переменных отсутствуют значения, ибо всё остальное правильно.

Comment: @lampa я в ответе написал что с этим кодом не так!)

Comment: Я сотый раз пишу есть значения в переменных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все мего элементарно!

`document.write(id2);` Вы пытаетесь вывести значение несуществующей переменной `id2`

**UPD:**

> Вы издеваетесь. Я вам говорю что не
> выводится значения даже после того как
> я поменял.

`кушать больше борща...`

почему работает?

```
<?php
$myrow['id2'] = 321;
$myrow['id'] = 890;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
idd = <?=$myrow['id2']?>;
id = <?=$myrow['id']?>;
document.write(idd);
document.write(id);
</script>
```

Comment: Да , но ни первое ни второе не выводятся

Comment: Туговат человек... нужно изменить переменную в javascript `id2` на `idd` или наоборот!

Comment: Вы издеваетесь. Я вам говорю что не выводится значения даже после того как я поменял.

Comment: У меня не выводятся почему то

Comment: Значит программирование явно не для Вас!

Comment: Нет. Для меня сейчас всё робит  сервер так сказать не настроен был

Comment: >почему работает?

Потому что у вас ID цифровые. А у спрашивающего - текстовые. А текст надобно в кавычки заключать

Comment: @knes Вы тоже издеваетесь?

----------------------

я писал для @lampa, Ну а кавычки нужны ли в данном случае не известно, возможно php отдает цифры.

--------------------------

Повторю лично для Вас кусочек из моего ответа - document.write(id2); Вы пытаетесь вывести значение несуществующей переменной id2

----------------------

Вы в своем ответе поправили переменные и все работает, но конкретно ТС этого так и не понял!

Comment: Надо срочно заводить стрелочки к комментариям, как в бизнес-линче. =/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:
Если не получится, значит у вас они еще на этапе PHP не задаются:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  id2 = "<?php print $myrow['id2']; ?>";
  id = "<?php print $myrow['id'];?>";
  alert('id2='+id2);
  alert('id='+id);
</script>
```

Если alert сработает верно, значит либо у вас строгий XHTML, либо в PHP запрещены короткие тэги.

Обновил: добавил кавычки. Так лучше?

Comment: Опять же присваивается, но не выводится вот что если посмотреть исходники страницы
    id2 = 8744db;
    id = 18499;
    alert('id2='+id2);
    alert('id='+id);

Comment: А если с кавычками?